# Is there a model of ZFC whose theory is decidable?

Tags: logic, set-theory

More formally: Is there $\mathcal M\models ZFC$ such that there is a Turing machine that decides for a given $\{\in\}$-sentence $\varphi$ whether $\varphi\in Th(\mathcal M)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is not. Godel's incompleteness theorems apply to ZFC exactly as they do to PA. In particular, ZFC is essentially undecidable - no complete consistent extension of ZFC is decidable *(remember that the complete consistent extensions of ZFC are exactly the theories of the models of ZFC)*.

- In fact we can prove the essential undecidability of ZFC just by applying the essential undecidability of PA as a blackbox, since from a completion of ZFC we can compute a completion of PA. More importantly, **theories interpreting an essentially undecidable theory are essentially undecidable** (and the interpretation of PA in ZFC is straightforward).

We can say more with a bit more work: no model of ZFC has a computable *atomic* theory. See [this Mathoverflow discussion](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/12426/is-there-a-computable-model-of-zfc). This is closely related to Tennenbaum's theorem, which says that no *nonstandard* model of PA has a computable atomic theory.